# How to define a Cron Expressions of Quartz 2

Tags: cron, expression, quartz-scheduler

I read corn expression tutorial [this](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html) and managed to make simple expressions like : 15 14 5 12 0 represents as

15(minutes)14(hours) 5(day-of-month) 12(month) 2(day-of-week) that means 
At 14:15 on day-of-month 5 and on Sunday in December.

I didn't understand how do I define the repeated expression. I can write corn expression.

Every day at 01:00 a.m. Should be 0 1 * * *.

how to write an expression every last day of the month(end of the month) at 01:00 am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

Daily at 1:00 A.M corn expression should be: 0 0 1 * * ?

The last day of any month at 1:00 A.M corn expression should be: 0 0 1 L * ?

I verified the expression by this http://www.cronmaker.com/. I have to apply it in my code now.